# Check string having unique character or not without additional data structure

Tags: java, strings, interview-questions

Here is my code without using additional data structures. Assuming all the characters are alphabetical and character checks are case-insensitive.

```
public static boolean isRepeated(String s) {
    if (s == null) {
        return true;
    }
    int length = s.length();
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        if (!checkChar(i, s.toUpperCase())) {// making all character to upper case.
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;

}

private static boolean checkChar(int i, String s) {
    char charAtI = s.charAt(i);
    //check all the character before that index;
    for (int k = 0; k < i; k++) {
        if (s.charAt(k) == charAtI)
            return false;
    }
    //check all the character after that index;
    for (int l = i + 1; l < s.length(); l++) {
        if (s.charAt(l) == charAtI)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

But it takes \$O(n^2)\$. Is there better way to do it, or some improvement?

To save complexity, I am using the other way, i.e. using an array.

```
public static boolean isRepeatedUsingArray(String s) {
        int[] charArray = new int[26];
        for(char c:s.toUpperCase().toCharArray()) {
            if(charArray[(int)c - 65] == 1) {
                return false;
            }
            charArray[(int)c - 65] = 1;
        }
        return true;

    }
```

Let me know your comments on this one as well.

Comment: What constitutes an "additional data structure"? I would consider your `charArray` to be a data structure.

Answer (score 3):

**1. Function name** seems to be misleading. It returns true if no repeating character is found, so I find `isNonRepeatedUsingArray` to be more appropriate.

**2. Basic input checks** - when I began trying your function, I set up a few tests (included in the final code) and some of them crashed. Your code should handle at least basic input values such as null, empty string, string with spaces.

```
public static boolean isNonRepeatedUsingArray(String inputStr) {
    if(inputStr == null || inputStr.isEmpty())
        return false;

    String s = inputStr.replaceAll(" ", "").toUpperCase();

    // other character stripping may be put here
```

**3. Checking for duplicates** - The algorithm itself can be improved by thinking in terms of set. I am not very familiar with Java language and I have used `HashMap` data structure, but the bottom idea is the following:

*if current element is already in the set, it is a duplicate. Else add it to the set.*

This solution also has the advantage that avoids hardcoding the number of allowed characters (26).

```
    Map<Character, Boolean> charDict = new HashMap<Character, Boolean>();
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        Character c = s.charAt(i);    
        if (charDict.containsKey(c))
            return false;

        charDict.put(c, true);
    }
```

HashMap operations have a complexity of `O(1)`, so function's overall complexity is `O(n)`, where n is string length.

**[edit]**
Based on `Bobby's` correct observation, a HashSet is a better choice (elements only, no key and values):

```
    HashSet<Character> charSet = new HashSet<Character>();
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        Character c = s.charAt(i);    
        if (charSet.contains(c))
            return false;

        charSet.add(c);
    }
```

**4. Tests** - it is a good habit to accompany a function with a test suite. It is particularly efficient when the code changes much (regressive testing) and helps to cover scenarios that are usually missed when developing (developers have a tendency to think in terms of making it work, not making it fail).

```
private static void printTestResult(String s) {
    boolean testRes = isNonRepeatedUsingArray(s);
    System.out.println("Repeating result for " + s + " is " + testRes);
}

public static void main(String []args){
    printTestResult("a");
    printTestResult("abcde");
    printTestResult("some random text");
    printTestResult("repeating");
    printTestResult(null);
}
```

**The final code**

```
import java.util.*;

public class HelloWorld{

    public static boolean isNonRepeatedUsingArray(String inputStr) {
        if(inputStr == null || inputStr.isEmpty())
            return false;

        String s = inputStr.replaceAll(" ", "").toUpperCase();

        Map<Character, Boolean> charDict = new HashMap<Character, Boolean>();
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            Character c = s.charAt(i);    
            if (charDict.containsKey(c))
                return false;

            charDict.put(c, true);
        }

        return true;
    }

    private static void printTestResult(String s) {
        boolean testRes = isNonRepeatedUsingArray(s);
        System.out.println("Repeating result for " + s + " is " + testRes);
    }

    public static void main(String []args){
        printTestResult("a");
        printTestResult("abcde");
        printTestResult("some random text");
        printTestResult("repeating");
        printTestResult(null);
    }
}
```

Comment: The function should be called `hasOnlyUniqueCharacters(String)` or `hasNoRepeatingCharacters(String)`. The `UsingArray` part sounds like an implementation detail which should not matter to the user of the function and `isNonRepeated` raises the question "what is not repeated".

Comment: Also there is no need to use a `Map`, a `Set`, especially `HashSet`, is perfect for this and carries the meaning how it is used much better.